# Unable to get the documents after creating a query index

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Code:**

```
var querySnapshot = await Firestore //
    .instance
    .collection('collection')
    .where('name', isEqualTo: ['foo'])
    .orderBy('time')
    .limit(1)
    .getDocuments();

print('${querySnapshot.documents}'); // prints []
```

It returns empty `List`.

---

**Database structure:**

[image]

---

**Index built**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing isn't an issue here.  Given the query and document you're showing, I'd always expect it to return no results.  You're using an array-contains type query on a field that isn't an array.  Your name field is a string, and strings can't be matched by array-contains queries.

If you intended for name to be an array, you'll need to modify the document so that it is actually an array with the string "foo" in it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't plan to use array, I want to use String, so, should I use `isEqualTo` instead of `arrayContains`? Does `isEqualTo` support Strings?

Comment: If you just want to search for a single exact string value, yes, use that instead.

Comment: Sir I tried that, but again it is not returning any list. I updated the code. Could you please check?

Comment: Don't pass an array.  Just pass a string.